# Is "whom" old fashioned?

Tags: word-usage

I'm 16 and I am wondering if using "whom" in a conversation (with other people of my age, or even with an adult) or in a text isn't old fashioned for somebody of my age. I am asking myself this question because I read that "whom" is considered by many as something that won't be used anymore.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mea culpa!

I'm not sure about *old fashioned* but it's certainly **not** archaic. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whom&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,whom;,c0) shows that the word has been used (in fact the usage has been increased in past few years) in books.

The pronoun *whom* has its specific purpose which is unlikely to be replaced by the other word. If you think that it has become old fashioned and *who* has replaced *whom* everywhere, be careful. Where *whom* goes, *who* may not.

All in all, 'whom' is used where it should be and it's not yet vanished! In fact, the word is used in the [latest BBC news](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-26933197).

*Whomsoever this letter is concerned to...* -- *Whosoever this letter...* is not used.

I hope you know [where to use what.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom)

Comment: Thanks that you appreciate and accept my answer but I recommend to wait for some time. That's how the site works. Others may come up with answers and after that you can choose the best among them.

Comment: Ok ! Also, I see that the comment section shouldn't be used to thank people for their answers, do you agree with it or does it feel rude if I don't do that ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise that's a big question. I certainly favor that if you want to thank (and you should, at least I deadly feel thanking someone) you should express it. However, the site says such comments are not allowed. That's because the comments are used to put some knowledge or information into the question. However, it's okay and people do thank adding some extra notes in their thank notes. That's fine and humanly!

Comment: @MaulikV -1 Your link really is the answer, the rest rather irrelevant. "Who" and "whom" have specific usages and you should follow this. Objective/prepositional phrase use is probably occurring less which is why the Ngram went that way. It has nothing to do with being old fashioned.

Comment: @user3169 you probably missed this line of mine - *I won't say that it's old fashioned, but certainly, this seems to be less frequently used since past few years.*

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, but how is this related to the proper usage of who vs. whom? At least if properly used the rules are rather clear, so I am still wondering where the case for "old fashioned" (as asked by the OP) is.

Comment: @MaulikV I'd like to see more concrete evidence that supports your claim "this seems to be less frequently used since past few years". You should check in your Google Ngram the smoothing and the year before making such an assertion: "the usage of whom at least in books has been markedly down". Actually, with a proper setting, Google Ngram shows exactly the opposite of what you claimed.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I told what I saw and the settings were default. I changed them and it's still showing the worm grounding. Which settings did you use?

Comment: @MaulikV Try smoothing of zero, and change the year to 2008. The default is only between 1800 and 2000.

Comment: @user3169 Two things - firstly -the OP accepted the answer which means he was not sure whether 'who' replaced 'whom' everywhere. Secondly, you are right. it's not the contest between who/whom but then the Ngram shows that the frequency of using the word 'whom' is getting decreased which **may** mean that word is substituted by some neutral word?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Okay, I check, confirm and edit the answer.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Changed the answer. Tahnks for drawing attention.

Comment: @MaulikV Hello, I don't understand, did the usage increased or decreased ? Beacause in the comments you are speaking about  a decreasing and in your edit you are speaking about an increasing !

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise the edit happened after the comments so consider the answer. It's trending in recent year. You could have simply clicked on the link.